# ASP.NET WebAPI Null value in post body?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-web-api

I have just started learning WebAPI today and I can't figure out why "account" is always null.

**Request**

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Request-Body: {"account":{"email":"awd","password":"awad","isNewsletterSubscribed":false}}
```

**WebAPI**

```
 public class AccountsController : ApiController
    {
        public void Post([FromBody] string account)
            {
                    // account is null
            }
    }
```

Shouldn't account contain a json string in this case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Shouldn't account contain a json string in this case?

That would depend on the specific `Content-Type` request header you set when you send the request. For example if you used `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` which is the default then your request body payload must have looked like this:

```
={"account":{"email":"awd","password":"awad","isNewsletterSubscribed":false}}
```

Notice the `=` character at the beginning. That's one of the biggest weirdest things I have ever encountered. Since you can bind only one parameter from the body if the request the Web API doesn't expect a parameter name, but just the value.

This being said, your request payload looks more like a JSON. So it would make far more sense to design a view model and use `Content-Type: application/json`  when sending the request. Binding a JSON object to a string is not common practice.

So:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public bool IsNewsletterSubscribed { get; set; }
}

public class AccountViewModel
{
    public UserViewModel Account { get; set; }
}
```

and then your controller action will simply take the view model as parameter. In this case yo udon't need to decorate it with the `[FromBody]` attribute because by convention in Web API the default model binder will attempt to bind complex types from the body of the request:

```
public class AccountsController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(AccountViewModel model)
    {
        // work with the model here and return some response
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```

Also notice that since HTTP is a request/response protocol it makes much more sense to have your Web API controller actions return response messages as shown in my example rather than just having some `void` methods. This makes the code more readable. You immediately understand how the server will respond and with what status code to the specified request.

Comment: the request header is "application/json; charset=utf-8"

Comment: Alright, see my updated answer for the proper way to design this using a view model that will match the JOSN structure.

Comment: It works, thank you! One last question. Why do I have to specify an additional AccountViewModel class with a property Account? Is this somehow integrated into the famework?

Comment: That's because of the form of your JSON object: It has an `account` property so you need to wrap everything in an outer class with a property with the same name. The model binder will attempt to match the exact same structure when performing the binding. If your request body payload looked like this: `{"email":"awd","password":"awad","isNewsletterSubscribed":false}` then you could have directly used the `UserViewModel` as parameter.